unity Navmesh Calculatepath always returning false value
I have created a maze, and after clicking, I want to draw the path that solves the maze from the given cursor position using lines. But no matter where I click, Navmesh.calculatepath always returns false.
Here is my code.
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        StartCoroutine(Makepath());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Makepath(){


    Ray Moveposition = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(Moveposition, out var hitposition))
    {
        Vector3 agentpos = agent.transform.position;
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();

        agent.SetDestination(hitposition.point);

        NavMesh.CalculatePath(agentpos, hitposition.point, NavMesh.AllAreas, path); 
        Debug.Log(path.corners.length + "<<<<Path.corner length");
        Debug.Log(agentpos + "<<<agentpos");
        Debug.Log(hitposition.point + "<<<hitposition.point");
    }
    yield return null;
}

and here is output I found in console


have you tried sampling the navmesh to get the nearest point to the hit?

Are you sure you to perform the Bake operation on the Navigation system?

Yes ofcourse I baked the map.

So, create another terrain. As big as the previous terrain and in its position. Before the bake operation on the new terrain, be sure to disable all other terrains. The bake operation causes problems when multiple terrains are active. Note: If your terrain is a prefab, make sure that no other terrain is active in the Scene when you want to bake it.
